# Changes via Gio.Settings don't take effect

Tags: python, gsettings

As the title suggests, I am trying to alter gsettings via python's Gio module on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ( a user over at Unix & Linux site said the script bellow works on Arch, so it may be Ubuntu-specific issue )

The settings get changed , but are not applied. Here's what I mean.

Consider the script bellow:

```
$> cat ~/py_bg.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from gi.repository import Gio
import os
import sys
pic_name = sys.argv[1]
settings = Gio.Settings.new("org.gnome.desktop.background")
settings.set_string("picture-uri", "file://" + os.getcwd() + "/" + pic_name)
settings.apply()
```

Executing the script does show the changes in `gsettings` , but the desktop actually remains unchanged

```
$> python ~/py_bg.py ZEN.jpg                                                    
$> gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri                       
'file:///home/xieerqi/WALLPAPERS/ZEN.jpg'
```

The issue persists with other schemas. 
How can  I troubleshoot this and make the script work ?

Comment: Anything interesting in `gsettings list-recursively  org.gnome.desktop.background`?

Comment: @muru nothing out of the ordinary `draw-background` is set  ` true` . Changes done via `dconf` or `gsettings` take effect, but not via this script .

Comment: Your code works for me in Ubuntu 16.04. Do you use any program other than Nautilus to draw on the desktop?

Comment: @FlorianDiesch  the only other thing I've used is Unity System Settings -> Appearance

Comment: For some odd reason , it started working now, after changing the line `from gi.repository import Gio` to `from gi.repository import Gio,Gtk`

Answer (score 0):

**I think I can provide some details to this.**

I ended up here after many hours of unsuccessful attempts at persisting data to my schema.

I'm using the c++ libraries `libgtkmm-3.0` `libglibmm-2.4`.

In short, the `import Gio,Gtk` does quite a few things under the hood.

The Gio library functions worked but complained a tad before I started an Gtk app. I think this is where you were before the Gtk import.

I still had problems getting the Gio code not complaining. The solution was to create a Gtk::Application object.

In my code that was

```
auto app = Gtk::Application::create(...);
```

Now they stopped complaining.

The GSettings object would not persist. Even though my carefully crafted schema compiled and the compiled schema was located at all places I thought was relevant.  `gsettings --schema-path` queries gave all the right feedback.

What finally did work was if I actually run the `Gtk::Application`. When I saw your comment about the `import Gtk` I suspected the import did more than the `#include<gtkmm>` did for me

```
app->run();
```

This made the settings persist.

I also had to modify the environment variable `GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR` the `XDG` variants did not work for me at all.

I imagine the imports Gio and Gtk does all this stuff for you.